# Or condition is not working with set_facts in my playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I created one playbook to run the tasks based on the test case so I have created like below

Here when I pass the **ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e stage=1**, it's skipping all the tasks, and when I debug the test_case* values I could see both are in a false state, So can some help me to work this code.

```
---
 - name: test
   hosts: localhost
   tasks:
     - name: setting the level
       set_fact:
        test_case_1: "{{ stage == 1 }}"
        test_case_2: "{{ stage == 1 or stage == 2 }}"
  
     - name: "running ls command"
       shell: "ls -l"
       register: testing
       when:
          - test_case_1 == true

     - debug:
           msg: "{{ testing.stdout_lines }}"
       when:
          - test_case_1 == true

     - name: "kickoff"
       shell: "df -Th"
       register: kick
       when:
          - test_case_2 == true

     - name: "printing kickoff"
       debug:
          msg: "{{ kick.stdout_lines }}"
       when:
          - test_case_2 == true
```

Below is the error results which I am getting

```
[root@server ~]# ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e stage=1


PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [setting the level] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [running ls command] *********************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [kickoff] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [printing kickoff] ***********************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0

[root@server ~]#
```

expected results should be, it should execute all the tasks from the play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are performing an integer comparison (`stage == 1`), but when you provide a value on the command line via `-e stage=1`, you are setting a string value.

You probably want to case the value of stage to an integer using the `int` filter.

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: setting the level
      set_fact:
        test_case_1: "{{ stage|int == 1 }}"
        test_case_2: "{{ stage|int == 1 or stage|int == 2 }}"
```

With this change, things seem to work as expected.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you could rewrite the second test like this:

```
{{ stage|int in [1, 2] }}
```

That simplifies things a bit.